# Leibniz's Rule Integration of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have to solve the following question :

"By n-fold differentiation of the function : $g(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} dt$

Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-x} dx = n! $ "

Firstly, I tried to solve g(x) and I got this far :

$g(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} dt\\
g'(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{-tx} dt\\
g'(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} -te^{-tx} dt$

I can't figure out how to integrate the final part and also link it to this equation $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n} e^{-x} dx = n! $

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you. I have now integrated the equation

Answer (score 1):

We can show that
\begin{align}
g(x)&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx}\,dt=\frac{1}{x}
\end{align}
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ a few times shows that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} -te^{-tx}\,dt\Big|_{x=1}&=-1 \\ \\
\int_0^{\infty} t^2 e^{-tx}\,dt\Big|_{x=1}&=2 \\ \\
\int_0^{\infty} -t^3 e^{-tx}\,dt\Big|_{x=1}&=-6
\end{align}
We can thus speculate that 
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x}\,dx=n!$$
And you may be able to use induction on 
$$\left[\frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\,dx\right]\Biggr|_{t=1}$$
to prove this conjecture.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seeing the method it makes clear sense now.